# Prove that $f\in L^2$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_A f_n = \int_Af$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ be a bounded, measurable susbset of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $(f_n) \subset L^2 (A)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $A$, then $f\in L^2(A)$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_A f_n = \int_Af$.

Clearly $f$ is measurable. We have to show that $\int_A f^2 < \infty$. Choose $\epsilon>0$. From uniform convergence we can find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_{n_0}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in A$ and some $n_0>N$. Now denote by $A^-$ the part of $A$ where $f$ is negative and by $A^+$ the part of $A$ where $f$ is positive. Since $f$ is measurable, both sets are measurable.

We have $-f(x)<\epsilon - f_{n_0}(x)$ thus $\int_{A^-} f^2< \int_{A^{-}}(\epsilon-f_{n_0})^2<\infty$ (since A is bounded).

Similarly, since $f(x)<\epsilon + f_{n_0}(x)$, we get $\int_{A^+} f^2< \int_{A^{+}}(\epsilon+f_{n_0})^2<\infty$ and we can conclude that $f\in L^2 (A)$.

It remains to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_A f_n = \int_Af$. First we establish convergence in $L^2$ on $A$:

$$\|f_n-f\|_2^2=\int_A |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2\,dx \leq m(A) \left(\sup_{x \in A}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\right)^2 \to 0$$

Now we can use CS inequality and conclude that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_A f_n = \int_Af$.

Is my derivation correct?

Comment: $L^p$ spaces are complete so it suffices to show that $f_n\stackrel{L^2}\longrightarrow f$  (which you did correctly) to verify that $f\in L^2$. Uniform convergence implies $L^\infty$ convergence, so we may use dominated convergence with $g=\sup_n \|f_n\|_\infty$ to justify the remaining claim.

Comment: Thanks, but my proof (as it is) is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Let$$g_n = f_n - f.$$Then $g_n$ converges uniformly to zero. Since$$\|g_n\|_2 \le m(A)\|g_n\|_\infty,$$we have what we need. Note that $A$ must be of finite measure, or this breaks down.